# Is it possible to use Stylus plugins with inline Stylus code embedded in a Jade file?

Tags: pug, stylus

I want to be able to create a directory of web page scratch files, where each file is a self-contained page.

This is pretty easy with regular HTML/CSS/JS:

```
<head>
    <style>
        p {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>lololol</p>
</body>
```

And it's similarly easy with Jade/Stylus/CoffeeScript:

```
head
    :stylus
        p
            color red
body
    p lololol
```

The thing is, there's no clear way to use Stylus plugins this way. Specifically, I'd like to use **[colorspaces.js](http://boronine.com/colorspaces.js/#stylus_support)** and **nib** to experiment with colors more effectively:

```
head
    :stylus
        @import 'nib'
        p
            color CIELCH(20.470, 74.265, 314.113)
            background-color linear-gradient(white, black)
body
    p lololol
```

## The workaround I'm currently using

---

You can fork Jade by changing [these lines](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/66fc35f9093f7721ac354815c804f944e3027a31/lib/filters.js#L28-41) like so:

```
  /**
   * Transform stylus to css, wrapped in style tags.
   */

  stylus: function(str, options){
+   colorspaces = require('colorspaces');
+   nib = require('nib');
    var ret;
    str = str.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
    var stylus = require('stylus');
-   stylus(str, options).render(function(err, css){
+   stylus(str, options).use(colorspaces()).use(nib()).render(function(err, css){
      if (err) throw err;
      ret = css.replace(/\n/g, '\\n');
    });
    return '<style type="text/css">' + ret + '</style>'; 
  },
```

And if you install Jade's dependencies (I had to `npm install commander` and `npm install mkdirp`), you can navigate to `/jade_fork/bin/` and do `./jade name_of_file.jade`.

---

But I'd prefer to stay on the main branch of Jade for maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Here is the best way I've found:

Save as e.g. `~/bin/jade`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var jade = require('jade');

jade.filters.stylus = // your code from above

require('jade/bin/jade');
```

It will work exactly as `/usr/local/bin/jade`, except it will use your code for compiling stylus, with nib etc.

---

**Old answer:**

I suggest you do it like this:

```
var jade = require('jade');

jade.filters.stylus = // your code from above

jade.compile( /* ... */ );
```

You lose out on the jade command line script, but you should be able to compile your files in this manner, while depending on jade master.